# I have an issue with chrome headless. It is not loading the webtop pages(Desktop applications embedded with web)

Tags: selenium, google-chrome

I have an issue with chrome headless. It is not loading the webtop pages(Desktop applications embedded with web). I have tried with all combinations, however it works well with chrome driver without headless.

I have added all possible arguments. The error while loading application is
Exception as below:

---

Something went wrong with the JSP error pages

Original Exception Message: `PRESENTATION_FRAMEWORK_PROTOCOLROUTER_DEVICE_NOTSUPPORTED`

StackTrace dump:

```
com.meridea.cs.error.BaseException: PRESENTATION_FRAMEWORK_PROTOCOLROUTER_DEVICE_NOTSUPPORTED
    at com.meridea.cs.presentation.control.ProtocolRouter.checkAccess(ProtocolRouter.java:578)
    at com.meridea.cs.presentation.control.ProtocolRouter.doProcess(ProtocolRouter.java:410)
    at com.meridea.cs.presentation.control.ProtocolRouter.doGet(ProtocolRouter.java:180)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.serviceProxied(ServletWrapper.java:307)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleFragment(CacheHook.java:562)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleServlet(CacheHook.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:259)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at dk.topdanmark.ca.security.TopProUserPoolFilter.doFilter(TopProUserPoolFilter.java:270)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at dk.topdanmark.ca.security.TopProLoginFilter.doFilter(TopProLoginFilter.java:266)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at dk.topdanmark.ca.security.TopProTokenLoginFilter.doFilter(TopProTokenLoginFilter.java:80)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4047)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1016)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:213)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
JSP error message: SRVE0190E: File not found: /jsp/en/html/error_Mobile.html

StackTrace dump
java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /jsp/en/html/error_Mobile.html
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor._processEDR(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:976)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.processEDR(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:957)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:485)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1404)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:196)
    at com.meridea.cs.presentation.errorhandler.ErrorHandler.handleError(ErrorHandler.java:64)
    at com.meridea.cs.presentation.control.ProtocolRouter.doProcess(ProtocolRouter.java:484)
    at com.meridea.cs.presentation.control.ProtocolRouter.doGet(ProtocolRouter.java:180)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.serviceProxied(ServletWrapper.java:307)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleFragment(CacheHook.java:562)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleServlet(CacheHook.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:259)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at dk.topdanmark.ca.security.TopProUserPoolFilter.doFilter(TopProUserPoolFilter.java:270)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at dk.topdanmark.ca.security.TopProLoginFilter.doFilter(TopProLoginFilter.java:266)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at dk.topdanmark.ca.security.TopProTokenLoginFilter.doFilter(TopProTokenLoginFilter.java:80)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4047)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1016)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:213)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
```

---

My added arguments:

```
options.addArguments("window-size=1400,800");
    options.addArguments("headless"); // only if you are ACTUALLY running headless  
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox")
    options.addArguments("ignore-certificate-errors");
    options.addArguments("allow-running-insecure-content");
    options.addArguments("--allow-insecure-localhost");
    options.addArguments("user-agent= Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0 like MacOS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53");
           
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and post the exception as text?

Comment: Done added exception as text